# Am I passing these variables properly? C Programming

Tags: c, variables, pointers

I am super beginner to C and I was wondering if these variables are being passed properly, I'd like their values to be altered in main. I'm mainly wondering if I am using & and * properly.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int assign(int *i, int *scores[]);

int main(void){
    int scores[30], i;

    assign(&i, &scores[0]);

    return 0;
}

int assign(int *i, int *scores[]){
    printf("Input scores:\n");
    for (i = 0; i < 30; i++){
        scanf("%d", *scores[*i]);
    }

}
```

Comment: Also I am getting an unresolved externals error and I don't know what that means.

Comment: I'm wondering that too. Why not try running it and seeing what happens?

Comment: I think the error came from choosing windows application in the set up of the file instead of console application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're passing far too many levels of indirection:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void assign(int *scores);

int main() {
    int scores[30];
    assign(scores);
    return 0;
}

void assign(int *scores) {
    int i;
    printf("Input scores:\n");
    for (i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
        scanf("%d", &scores[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Also I like that you used i as a local variable, that does make it easier.

Comment: @ShaneBird: yes. that's true.

Comment: You don't get the final value of `i` in the main function after calling `assign` (in the case you need it for something).

Comment: Also I'm confused as to why we use &scores[i] instead of *scores[i]. I thought that &scores[i] would assign the scanned values to the address of score[i].

Comment: `scores` has the type (more or less) of `int *`. `scores[i]` has the type of `int`. `*scores[i]` attempts to dereference something that is not a pointer, so that would be an error. `&scores[i]` returns a `int *`. `scanf` expects the arguments that it will place data into to be pointers.

Answer (score 1):

&scores has type `char[30]*`. Assign wants `char**`. Why add the extra indirection anyway?
Use:

```
int assign(int *i, int scores[static 30]);
```

Call with:

```
assign(&i, scores);
```

Rationale:
C always passes by value, so using pointers was right.
But C cannot copy arrays, they instead decay to a pointer to the first element for nearly every use.
Also, if a prototype seems to expect an array, it actually expects a pointer instead.
The added `static 30` are a guarantee to the compiler (and a marker for readers / programmers that at least `30` elements are accessible using aforementioned pointer.

Also, don't forget to derefference the proper number of times. Currently you don't.

Comment: @MattMcNabb: Only after changing the prototype completely, and it built on an obvious mis-understanding of C arrays. My proposed change uses idiomatic C arrays.

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify your code with much less `*` and `&`. Also, you can pass an array directly as a pointer. No need to do `&scores[0]`.

```
#include <stdio.h>



int assign(int i, int* scores){
    printf("Input scores:\n");
    for (i = 0; i < 30; i++){
        scanf("%d", &scores[i]);
    }

}

int main(void){
    int scores[30], i;
    assign(i, scores);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int assign(int *i, int scores[]);

int main(void){
    int scores[30], i, j;

    assign(&i, scores);
    for(j=0;j<i;++j)
        printf("%d %d\n", j, scores[j]);
    return 0;
}

int assign(int *outSize, int scores[]){
    int i = 0;
    printf("Input scores:\n");
    for (i = 0; i < 30; ++i){
        if(1!=scanf("%d", &scores[i]))
            break;
    }
    return *outSize = i;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should pass the size of array to the function as well. C type array does not know about its size. We should avoid the uses of magical/hard coded value wherever possible.

```
//main function
int scores[30], i;
int size = sizeof(scores)/sizeof(scores[0]);

// pass the size information as well
int assign(int *i, int *scores[]), int size) {

}
```